# Proof that in a metric space the closure of a set is a closed set

Tags: probability-theory

I can't find a proof using the definitions I was given in my university course and can't for the life of me figure it out by myself.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

A set $U \subseteq X$ is **open** if for any $x \in U$ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that the open ball $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq U$. A set $F \subseteq X$ is **closed** if $F^c=X\setminus F$ is open.

Now, let $A\subseteq X$. The **closure** of $A$ is the set $\overline{A} = \{x \in X: \text{there exists a sequence } (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \subseteq A \text{ such that } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} d(x,x_n)=0 \}$.

The fact I'm trying to prove is: $\overline{A}$ is a closed set.

My (one of many) try:

$\overline{A}$ is closed if and only if $(\overline{A})^c$ is open. Suppose it's not. Then there's an $x \in (\overline{A})^c$ such that for any $\epsilon >0$ the open ball $B(x,\epsilon) \not\subseteq (\overline{A})^c$, which means there's $y \in \overline{A}$ such that $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$. I don't know how to proceed from there, since the choice of $y$ depends on $\epsilon$ it doesn't give me a sequence in $A$ convergent to $x$ which is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close!  The choice of $y$ does depend on $\epsilon$, so you can make many choices - different ones for each $\epsilon$.  In particular, if for each $n$ you pick $y_n$ using $\epsilon = 1/n$, can you then prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}y_n = x$?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. I still miss one little detail though, what if some $y_n \in \overline{A} \setminus A$? Doesn't that create a problem if the whole sequence is not in $A$ if the definition of $\overline{A}$ requires it?

Comment: I can't edit my comment, so: nevermind, I think I got it: if $y_n \in \overline{A} \setminus A$ then there's a sequence in $A$ convergent to $y_n$, so I can find an element in this sequence which is in the open ball $B(x,\epsilon)$ by choosing $\epsilon' = \epsilon - d(x,y_n)$. So I just substitute $y_n$ by this element in the final sequence. Thank you very much!